# Having a cycled (interval) pictures on pre-loaded page through a directory

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, cycle

I am currently working for a library that would like to have a webpage designed digital signage. Most of it has been designed with widgets and through a program called Xcite Pro. I was unable to find any widgets that will allow me to do a slideshow from a directory that will cycle through. I do know the foundations to JavaScript and php.

I do not know how to take a directory and have JavaScript run through an entire directory into a array with picture values. I would like to use the `setInterval()` command but I seem to only know how to search through a directory by php. I did find a explanation on this site that tells me how to use php to search through and then pull all pictures to be shown. If i can get that to all go into an array that could be used with JavaScript on the site that would actually work fine. The link for that explanation is [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595113/html-javascript-iterate-through-all-elements-of-local-server-side-folder).

Currently I am just using a folder called pics in my main file. So my directory is "pics" nothing to special. I have seen some things being talked about html5 using a new file search function but that sounds more like for finding particular files rather then taking the entire components of a folder into an array.

Edited 12/23/2013 Per PHPGlue Request and help.

So far the code that I have played with are:

Test html (Main Page)

```
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Basic XHTML Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>President Obama is from Hawaii</p>

<p><img id="scroller" alt="" src="pics/test.jpg" width="600" height="400"/></p>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='common.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='pics\imagefun.php'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Common js File in main directory with main page

```
// common.js
//<![CDATA[
var doc = document, bod = doc.body, IE = parseFloat(navigator.appVersion.split('MSIE')[1]);
function gteIE(version, className){
  if(IE >= version){
    bod.className = className;
  }
}
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
//]]>
```

Finally I have 2 pictures in a picture folder along with a imagefun php file.

```
// imagefun.php
<?php
$imgs = implode(array_merge(glob('*.png'), glob('*.jpg')), "', '");
echo "//<![CDATA[
var imgs = ['$imgs'], ni, iA = [];
for(var i in imgs){
  ni = new Image; ni.src = imgs[i]; iA[i] = ni;
}
var pre = onload, iN = 0, iL = imgs.length-1, imgElementId = E('scroller');
imgElementId.src = imgs[0];
onload = function(){
  if(pre)pre();
  imgElementId.src = iA[0];
  setInterval(function(){
    if(iN >= iL)iN = 0;
    imgElementId.src = iA[++iN];
  }, 2000);
}
//]]>";
?>
```

PHPGlue-- Thank you for all the time that you have put into this. Really not trying to be a pain at all and I really do appreciate all of your patience. I have made sure to swap names based on my file structures. Based on what I see for the basic ideas of the code I would think it should work. As I said though when I load to test it, it will only show the picture I defaulted on the load and then never change. One thing that I have noticed is that if you take the code of the image fun php code and run just that, all it returns is an output of //=IL)iN = 0; imgElement.src = iA[++iN]; }, 2000; } //]]>   If I am right then that string of output should be similar to the whole thing rather then just a fragment of a line like it is. I do believe if I am understanding the goal of this code we are having it spit out some code into the src location of the picture location?

Ultimately if possible I would like to have a cloud based file location that I could use to have an individual who works here store pictures in that file and then have the website pull all files in that location to be loaded to the page one at a time at an interval of about 15000ms. I would appreciated any comments or recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up resolving this myself. Thank you for all the help.

This was a multi parter either way.
I created a php cycler code
Note** This code will actually run through all that was needed just in php. Sadly though as I wanted this to show up on a web page that would cycle on a timer I needed to use some javascript coding. This caused me to change parts of what was used. If you want to do the same thing you drop all code after you have created the pics array or you can even keep up to the point of the forwards and backwards array to be passed into javascript.

```
<?php
// create a variable to hold the directory location
$Dir = "..\Directory\pics";

// Variable to directory
$dirOpen = opendir($Dir);

// Need to start with a main array
$pics = array();
// Need two arrays for going forward and back
$forwards = array();
$backwards = array();


// Need variables for the program
$c = 0;
$d = 0;
$e = 0;
$i = 0;
$f = 0;


// Need to run through all files in folder and store into an array
while ($curFile = readdir($dirOpen))
{
if(strpos($curFile,'.jpg') !== false)
{
    $pics[$i] = $curFile;
    ++$i;
}
}
closedir($dirOpen);

// declare variables to count previous opening of file
$a = count($pics);  // number of pics in the folder
$b = count($pics) - 1; // need to account for starting at 0


// run through pics array fowards
while($f < $a)
{
$forwards[$f] = $pics[$f];
++$f;
}

// run through the pics array backwards
while($b > -1)
{
$backwards[$c] = $pics[$b];
--$b;
++$c;
}
// variables for the functions us
// use function for forward pics
/*function forward($array, $a)
{
$d = 0;

if($d == $a)
{
    $d = 0;
    return "pics/".$array[$d];
    ++$d;
}
else
{
    return "pics/".$array[$d];
    ++$d;
}

}

function backward($backwards, $b)
{
if ($e == $b)  // going to have a conflict with B becuase right now it should be at       -1 or 0. need to compare to the value of -1 and have it reset to the max when reached.
{

}   

}
*/




/*// Test the output of each array
foreach($pics as $imgs)
echo $imgs . "<br />";

foreach($forwards as $fors)
echo $fors . "<br />";

foreach($backwards as $backs)
echo $backs . "<br />";
*/

// $forwards and $backwards are the arrays to use for pics cycling

?>
```

To pass onto the java script I had to use the following code on another php page created to work with all html design of the main page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="myForm">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p class="auto-style1"><img alt="" src="" id="pics" height="400" width="300"/></p>

<?php include 'imgCycler.php'; ?>

<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA [ */
var forwards = <?php echo json_encode($forwards); ?>;
var backwards= <?php echo json_encode($backwards); ?>;
var max = <?php echo $a ?>;
var count  = 0;

function changePic()
{
document.myForm.pics.src='pics/' +forwards[count];
//document.myForm.pics2.src='pics/'+backwards[count];
++count;
if (count == max)
{
    count = 0;
}
}

var start = setInterval('changePic()',5000);
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Again PHPGlue thank you for all the help you offered. Hope this is useful for anyone else that wishes to do something similar. Please let me know if there are any questions on the code.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by making a `common.js` file:

```
// common.js
//<![CDATA[
var doc = document, bod = doc.body, IE = parseFloat(navigator.appVersion.split('MSIE')[1]);
function gteIE(version, className){
  if(IE >= version){
    bod.className = className;
  }
}
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
//]]>
```

Now put the script below in the same folder you keep your images in:

```
// imagefun.php
<?php
$imgs = implode(array_merge(glob('*.png'), glob('*.jpg')), "', '");
echo "//<![CDATA[
var imgs = ['$imgs'];
for(var i in imgs){
  new Image().src = imgs[i];
}
var pre = onload, iN = 0, iL = imgs.length-1, imgElement = E('imgElementId');
imgElement.src = imgs[0];
onload = function(){
  if(pre)pre();
  imgElement.src = imgs[0];
  setInterval(function(){
    if(iN > iL)iN = 0;
    imgElement.src = imgs[iN++];
  }, 2000);
}
//]]>";
?>
```

Change the `imgElementId` to yours inside `E('imgElementId')`. `E('imgElementId')` must refer to an  `<img id='imgElementId' />` tag.

Now on your HTML page, refer to this JavaScript page as PHP, at the bottom of your body:

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src='common.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='path/imagefun.php'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, change `src='path/` to your image folder path, and add or subtract the correct `, glob('*.jpg')`s and the like, to suit your needs.

Notes:

`E(id)` gets your Element by id. `bod.className` changes to the `<body class='njs'>` to `<body class='js'>`, assuming you have the class attribute `njs` in your HTML body tag, for CSS without JavaScript *(progressive enhancement)*. `gteIE(version, className)` is for Internet Explorer versions greater than or equal to a number passed as `version`, changing that version or greater's body class attribute to the `className` argument, because IE10+ won't accept HTML IE comments for CSS changes. `imgfun.php` caches the images into your Browser memory based on globs found in the folder the script resides in. Then, once these images are loaded into your Browser cache, they are cycled through using setInterval.

Comment: I tried the code but it does not seem to load any pictures. I am sure I must be missing something but I am unsure as to what. I created the js document just as you said. I changed all referencing name structures to the correct ones. On the test page I created a <img id="scroller" alt="" /> tag and have that referenced in the code. When it loads it shows nothing though. I am loading in IE. I wanted to add code to show you but this comment box is limited. Do you know what could cause a problem?

Comment: I looked through the code some more and I have some more questions. I noticed that you reference an array that fills but I am not seeing how the code knows where to fill from. Even by putting the code in the pics folder how does written code determine to pull the files from its location in the file? Also If I try to just run the code the you listed as the imagefun.php it echo's out parts of the code. The code it shows is // =iL)iN=0; imgElementId.src=iA[++iN];2000;} //]]> Now if I understand this it should actually only show up as a file name? such as mypic.jpg?

Comment: Because `glob()` gets files from the folder it's in and returns an Array that I `implode()` into a String. Anything in double quotes in PHP interprets simple variables like `$imgs`. Those files need to show up as a file name. The loop with `new Image().src` is just assigning each image into the Browser cache.

Comment: The code above shows $imgs with single quotations. Does that need to be double quotations? Is there a way I can post the code so you can see what I have? As it stands nothing happens when I load my html that has the element id for pics and also the call for the javascript of both the common and imagefun files. Also based on the logic will for(var i in imgs) work or does it need to be a foreach statement?

Comment: Single quotes inside double quotes appear as single quotes in PHP. `implode()` just puts `', '` between each element of the Array, so it needs the quotes on the ends. The entire `echo` statement is in double quotes. That is PHP outputting JavaScript. JavaScript does not have a foreach loop. If you put the path to your `path/imagefun.php`, it should show JavaScript. Unlike JavaScript, PHP does not break lines until it sees a semicolon `;` that's not inside a String. What is your imageElementId?

Comment: If you put the path to your `path/imagefun.php` in your Browser Address Bar it should show JavaScript.

Comment: if i type in the full path such as file:///C:/Users/administrator/Documents/My%20Web%20Sites/pics/imagefun.php is what is returned when i put in my location. It returnes php code line by line. I have named my elementId as 'scroller'. From what I remember having the single quotations are to cause a break so the php will understand it. Based on there being " with the echo by putting ' that will be recognized on the php code as " correct? basically an inversion? So when we have imgElementId = E('scroller'); that will cause php to see it as E("scroller"); correct?

Comment: Naturally, I meant a Web Browser, since this is Web Programming. Firefox is a great Browser for Developers. You have to run PHP through a Server, like Apache. I use the XAMPP package with Apache, MySQL, FileZilla, Mercury, and Tomcat, on my PC, for testing before going live. I don't really use Tomcat, but I use the rest. Once set up, your files should be in the xampp folder, which you should have downloaded into your C drive directly. Your htdocs, found in your xampp folder, is referenced as localhost or 127.0.0.1 in you Browser Address bar. You should get some books o PHP. Lots to learn.

Comment: I do have a php book. Do you have any that you recommend as I am always willing to learn. I also already have mysql, filezilla, and apache already set on my pc. The code should work but it is not working. I am also using microsoft expression web4 to help with design. I am not sure about your comment with "Naturally, I meant a Web Browser,.." I understand that this is web programming. Everything I have been doing is through a web browser. I can also put my computer file locations in the URL in my browser to see what comes up. Which is what i did...

Comment: I believe I see what you might have been mentioning. I have moved all of the files that I was working with into the inetpub folder that was created when I installed apache. This still did not make anything work but it should now be in the correct folder to be run through the server side. On a side note though all php documents that I have have no problem running. Whether they are in my documents or in the inetpub folder.

Comment: You can usually run a document with a .php extension through a Browser as far as regular HTML markup is concerned. The problem is that it won't translate PHP unless it's routed through a Server.

Comment: Lets say that my problem is not PHP being Translated. As I stated I have it set up on this computer so that it will be translated. My problem is the code litterally does nothing. I need to find out why and translation is not the issue. I can run other PHP code. Lets say like even just an echo statement will work. The code that you have given me is not working though. I am curious as to what in the code you supplied would be wrong with the code that I am using. I assume that you tested the code you supplied to be sure it works?

Comment: You need an HTML `<img id='imgElementId' />` tag, that matches the JavaScript code `E('imgElementId')`. Really, I would need to see all of your code to know the problem. Edit your post and I'll try and help.